# Does anyone make a spacer for SPD cleats?

Tags: shimano, spd, cleat

I have a pair of cycling shoes that accept a two-bolt cleat, but require a spacer between cleat and sole to be compatible with Shimano SPD pedals. My pedal and cleat package did not come with spacers.

Does anyone make spacers of varying heights for such a situation?

Comment: See [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/21766/163). Recommendations include ask your local bike shop, or make your own out of plastic milk jugs.

Comment: This is not clear "clean and".  I suspect you mean cleat and sole.

Comment: You may find spacers mean the cleat is lower than the sole and hits the ground. Its personal preference but I like being able to walk without the cleat hitting the ground and damgeing smooth surfaces (e.g. Concrete, cafe floors etc) .

Answer (score 2):

As Kibbee said, making your own out of a milk jug or soda/beer can is probably the easiest way to go.  The spacer doesn't need to have the exact same footprint as the cleat to work, so you don't need to be too concerned with the sizing/shape.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the spacers that you are looking for I.e. 2 bolt SPD spacers.

Shimano PD-M8000 SPD Road Bicycle Cleat Spacer Set - YL8098030

Comment: Shopping links are usually discouraged because they are eventually obsoleted, but this says "Currently unavailable. We don't know when or if this item will be back in stock." already 15 minutes after posting.

Comment: The Answerer has included the part number, which can be bought from any Shimano dealer, so it's still a good answer @ojs

Comment: I was about to write an answer that you can't make such spacers because one side of the spacer needs to be soft plastic, and another side metal having teeth that dig into the sole. Apparently Shimano has managed to make spacers, by making it entirely of metal, and matching the cleat side to the cleat teeth so that the cleat teeth go in nicely to the spacer. This is the answer, +1, you can't make it from milk jugs or beer cans because you really need the hard teeth that dig into the sole material.

Comment: So, is it now "commercial spam is OK if it's for Amazon" or "commercial spam is OK if they're not actually selling the product"?